# Which algorithm is used in google's tesseract-OCR for Recognition?

Tags: machine-learning, ocr, tesseract

Which algorithm is used in google's tesseract-OCR for Recognition?Is it Neural Network?

Answer (score 6):

[This paper](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/docs/blob/master/tesseracticdar2007.pdf) in [the tesseract source](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) provides a deep overview of the technology.

Notably:

> Blobs are organized into text lines, and the lines and regions are
>   analyzed for fixed pitch or proportional text.
>
> [...]
>
> Recognition then proceeds as a two-pass process. In the first pass, an
>   attempt is made to recognize each word in turn. Each word that is
>   satisfactory is passed to an adaptive classifier as training data. The
>   adaptive classifier then gets a chance to more accurately recognize
>   text lower down the page.
>
> [...]
>
> Once the text lines have been found, the baselines are fitted more
>   precisely using a quadratic spline.
>
> [...]
>
> The baselines are fitted by partitioning the blobs into groups with a
>   reasonably continuous displacement for the original straight baseline.
>   A quadratic spline is fitted to the most populous partition, (assumed
>   to be the baseline) by a least squares fit.

The paper does not explicitly state whether it uses a neural network, but given the content I would say it's likely, at least for parts of it.

For more on line-finding, see *R. Smith, “A Simple and Efficient Skew Detection Algorithm via Text Row Accumulation”, Proc. of the 3rd Int. Conf. on Document Analysis and Recognition (Vol. 2), IEEE 1995, pp. 1145-1148.*

Comment: Thanks for the links :)

Comment: @ChiroOdhora Can you please accept it (check-mark below the voting arrows) so that it will no longer remain "unanswered"? :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `About` part of [tesseract github](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract#about) repo:

> Tesseract 4 adds a new **neural net (LSTM) based** OCR engine which is
> focused on line recognition

The algorithm is using LSTM model to extract the text.

For more information, you can see [Modernization Efforts](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/docs/das_tutorial2016/6ModernizationEfforts.pdf) of page `How Tesseract uses LSTMs...`

So, **yes**, it is based on the neural network.